# Problem making gnuplot parse date and time like "2022-01-24 05:36:22"

Tags: datetime, gnuplot, strftime

It seems my gnuplot knowledge is getting rusty; at least I don't see what's wrong:

I have a data file that looks like this (the actual file has more than 50000 lines, fields are separated by TABs):

```text
#date-and-time(0)   1(1)    5(2)    9(3)    12(4)   13(5)   170(6)  174(7)  179(8)  180(9)  181(10) 182(11) 184(12) 194(13) 195(14) 197(15) 198(16) 199(17) 201(18) 202(19) 225(20) 226(21) 227(22) 228(23) 232(24) 233(25) 234(26) 241(27) 242(28) 245(29)
2022-01-24 05:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2022-01-24 06:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2022-01-24 06:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
2022-01-24 07:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

The gnuplot session looks like this:

```gnuplot
Terminal type is now 'qt'
gnuplot> plot "attrlog.short" using 1:6 with linesp
Warning: empty x range [2022:2022], adjusting to [2001.78:2042.22]
Warning: empty y range [100:100], adjusting to [99:101]
gnuplot> set dataf sep tab
gnuplot> set form x "%F %T"
gnuplot> set timefmt "%F %T"
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> repl
2022-01-24 05:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:2:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 05:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:2:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 06:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:3:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 06:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:3:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 06:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:4:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 06:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:4:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 07:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:5:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 07:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:5:         warning: Bad time format in string
Warning: empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
Warning: empty y range [95:95], adjusting to [94.05:95.95]
gnuplot> set form x "%Y-%m-%d %T"
gnuplot> set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %T"
gnuplot> repl
2022-01-24 05:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:2:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 06:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:3:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 06:36:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:4:         warning: Bad time format in string
2022-01-24 07:06:22 130 100 100 100 95  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 10...
attrlog.short:5:         warning: Bad time format in string
Warning: empty x range [1.64298e+09:1.64298e+09], adjusting to [1.62655e+09:1.65941e+09]
Warning: empty y range [95:95], adjusting to [94.05:95.95]
gnuplot>
```

Initially I had used "%F" instead of "%Y-%m-%d", but even now it won't work, and I don't see why.
The example session was made with gnuplut 5.2 patchlevel 2, while originally the problem was found in 5.2 patchlevel 8.

The data format should be obvious: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Check `help time_specifiers`: `%F` and `%T` are only for output, not for input as you are trying.  Output: `set format x '%F %T'` will work, but Input: `set timefmt '%F %T'` will not work according to documentation.

Comment: `set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %T"` will not work. That's why you get `"Bad time format in string"`. Change it to `set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: Stupid me: You are right: I had read about `%F`, but missed `%T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders `%F` (date) and `%T` (time) are *not* valid for `set timefmt`.
So when using these commands instead, things should work smoothly:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

plot "attrlog.short" u 1:6 w lp
```

Details can be found in `help time_specifiers`:

> `%F` and `%T` are only for output, not for input as you are trying.

- Output: `set format x '%F %T'` will work, but
- Input:  `set timefmt '%F %T'` will *not* work according to documentation.
  Change it to `set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

Be aware:
If you want to plot the column with `95` in your data example

- and if your separator is whitespace (default), you have to specify column 7.
- and if you explicitly have TAB as separator (that's what you specify later) and the space within your date/time is "normal" space then column 6 is fine.

Comment: @U.Windl not sure, but could well be that in this case the order plays a role. That's why I typically put all commands into a script file which starts with `reset session` and load this script file in gnuplot console via `load 'myScript.gp'`. With this, I start with default conditions and can easily change via text editor and reload the modified script again. Otherwise some persistent settings might lead to confusion and unexpected results.

Comment: Usually I do the same once the plot meets my expectations, but I had the problem while "building" a new plot. And saving commands that seem to be wrong didn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Note: When *editing* the question, the TABs are still there in the sample datafile, but no longer if you copy and paste from the display.